# Allauth {% providers_media_js %} giving need more than 1 value to unpack error

Tags: django, django-allauth

```
ValueError at /accounts/login/
**need more than 1 value to unpack**
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
need more than 1 value to unpack
Exception Location: C:\xampp\htdocs\Aptana Workspace\ktj14\allauth\utils.py in import_attribute, line 76
```

This is the error messsage i get with {% providers_media_js %}

my settings.py file

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount'
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
                           'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
                           'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
                'facebook':{    'SCOPE':['email'],
                                'AUTH_PARAMS':{'auth_type':'reauthenticate'},
                                'METHOD':'js_sdk',
                                'LOCALE_FUNC':'en-US'
                                },
                'google':{    'SCOPE':['email'],
                                'AUTH_PARAMS':{'auth_type':'reauthenticate'},
                                'METHOD':'js_sdk',
                                'LOCALE_FUNC':'en-US'
                                }

                           }
```

These are the allauth related settings i've used. allauth is added in the INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: share your settings related to allauth..

Comment: i've edited the question with the settings

Comment: It is expecting a `LOCALE_FUNC` settings - https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth

Comment: added 'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable' still the same problem is there

Comment: check the way they have showing in the example. It expects a tuple, not a string. Hence the error. Or , just try `'LOCALE_FUNC':('en-US', )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOCALE_FUNC` should be set to the full path of a callable function. Here, `"path.to.callable"` is just an example that is not to be taken literraly, as that would mean need to create a file `"path/to.py"` with a `def callable` defined inside.

I suggest you avoid a path to a callable and directly inline the callable, like this:

```
'LOCALE_FUNC':  lambda request: 'en-US
```